# A useful userscript for uploading images

Tags: discussion

One of our fellow SE-mods created [a nice little userscript that gives you some additional options when uploading images.](https://stackapps.com/questions/3507/thumbnail-uploader)

> When you upload an image using the SE uploading dialog, it gets
>   uploaded in exactly the same size that the file is in. For large
>   images, this can be a problem since they take up a lot of space and
>   screw the alignment. The uploader doesn't allow for resizing (except
>   by manually changing the URL to one ending in s, m, or l.
>
> This script provides an improved upload dialog:

[image]

[Go here for more info](https://stackapps.com/questions/3507/thumbnail-uploader)